# Trouble using convertchar and thestring inside a LaTeX command or table

Tags: macros, stringstrings

I'm trying to generate page references inside a command that defines a row of a table, with the name of the label being referenced generated as a result of some string maniupulation using stringstrings.  Here's a much simplified version of what I'm trying to do, generating a reference to the OPSFOO label based on a command parameter of FO_O, with the string processing removing underscores and prepending OPS:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand{\opind}[2]{
  \convertchar[q]{OPS#2}{\_}{}
  #1 & #2 & \pageref{\thestring} \\
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{l l l}
    \opind{1}{FO\_O} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\label{OPSFOO} FOO \\
\end{document}
```

That fails with the error "! Undefined control sequence.
 \thestring"

I thought perhaps there was something wrong with using \thestring inside a command, so I tried putting it directly into the table entry like this:

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{l l l}
     \convertchar[q]{OPSFO\_O}{\_}{}
     1 & FO\_O & \pageref{\thestring} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But that gets essentially the same error.  So I started wondering if there's just a problem with using \thestring as an argument to \pageref.  Apparently not; if I do the string manipulation outside the table, everything works fine:

```
\convertchar[q]{OPSFO\_O}{\_}{}
\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{tabular}{l l l}    
   1 & FO\_O & \pageref{\thestring} \\
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Is there anything I can do to get the string manipulation and the use of \pageref{\thestring} to work in the command that's called inside the table, as in the first code listing above?

Comment: The problem seems to be, that `\thestring` is expanded locally in the first table cell, but then lost in the 3rd. one, since table cells are `groups`

Comment: Can you tell what you expect in argument `#2`? There can be much faster ways to solve your problem. Is lowercasing connected to this? Perhaps it's better if you state your complete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Christian Hupfer's comment to the problem, but avoiding using a global variable as in his answer:

```
\newcommand{\opind}[2]{
  #1 & #2 & \convertchar[q]{OPS#2}{\_}{} \pageref{\thestring} \\
}
```

Comment: This is also possible, but I thought, you would stick to `\convertchar` in the first cell. I see, that this is not necessary in your case

Answer (score 3):

According to the `stringstrings` documentation, `\thestring` is only a `\edef`ined macro, valid only in the local group (a table cell here). To transport the content to the later table cells, it's necessary to make a global `\edef`, i.e. using an `\xdef` with some helper macro, say `\theglobalstring`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcommand{\opind}[2]{
  \convertchar[q]{OPS#2}{\_}{}
  \xdef\theglobalstring{\thestring}
  #1 & #2 & \pageref{\theglobalstring} \\
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{l l l}
    \opind{1}{FO\_O} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\label{OPSFOO} FOO \\

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: There might be other ways of course ;-)